# break statement won't exit loop

Tags: c++, loops, break

Using the following code, I'm for some reason not able to exit the provided for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi)/sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi[0]); i++){
                if(boolForCharIsDigi[i] == false){
                    hasPassed = false;
                    std::cin >> turnsDefined;
                    std::cout << "You may only use numbers to define the amount of turns. No decimals either." << std::endl << std::endl;
                    break;
                }else if(boolForCharIsDigi[i] == true){
                    hasPassed = true;
                }
}
```

Vars: `boolForCharIsDigi` is bool array containing both false and true values.
`turnsDefined` is a simple `std::string`. `hasPassed` is another normal bool value either true/false.

**Exactly what I want do to:** Using the break statement, I want to exit the for loop. (quite simple).

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi)` and `sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi[0])` ??

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)!

Comment: Use hasPassed and the current condition for the for-loop. The  initialize it to true. You don't need to the break.

Comment: @gldraphael Computed, it returns the value (length) of a user input char array. It basically creates a bool for each element in a char array.

Comment: @JustinDanielson Doesn't work with the rest of the code. I'd like to know why the break statement isn't doing anything. And I really mean anything.

Comment: @Code0 `sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi)` only works for statically allocated arrays

Comment: @PeterT As I said, that's not the error (it does work without me declaring it static) My question is: Why does the break statement in the above code not do anything.

Comment: @Code0 how do you know it doesn't work? Have you tried stepping through?

Comment: @Code because to me it looks like it works just fine: http://ideone.com/281Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did wrong: My `break` statement only exited one single nested loop. The outer loop simply restarted the inner one. So what I did was add a bool and let the outer loop check if the inner loop set it to `true` so it exits.